# Exporting data from OLEDB to Excel using SSIS ExecuteSQLTask Control

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I want to export OLEDB(SQL Server) to Excel using EXEcute SQL Task
i given a select query with where clause...

i want to output of the query will go to Excel sheet

I used EXecuteSQL Task in that, connection, ConnectionType, SqlStatement..

I dont know next level and what control and transaformation will be used..

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do these sort of things in your Control Flow. What need is a `Data Flow Task`, drag one of these on your control flow and double click it to go to the Data Flow.

On the Data Flow you can use an `OLE DB Source` and either query a whole table/view or enter your select query. Then use an `Excel Destination` to write the output of the OLE DB Source too.

Comment: Sorry I had an Where Condition (Clause)

Comment: Then change the OLE DB Source's `Data access mode` to `SQL Command` and insert your select query, including the where clause, into that text field.